# ES6 import issue

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

I am creating a Single page application base on MVC, and I am stuck with a small issue. I am exporting the reference of `controller` class and I am importing it at a few places and it is working fine but when I am trying to import it into a specific file, it's not working, I spent a lot of time, but couldn't figure it out. I am sure I am missing some obvious thing. Here is my code([Link to Repo for more details](https://github.com/iiison/flash)):

**Controller**([Actual File](https://github.com/iiison/Flash/blob/master/js/controller.js)):

```
class Controller extends Base {
  constructor(){
    super()
    //more code
  }
  //more code
  static create() {
    return new Controller() // planning to make a singleton later on
  }
}
const controller = Controller.create()

export default controller
```

**Model**(import works in this one, [Actual file](https://github.com/iiison/Flash/blob/master/js/models/Model.js)):

```
import controller from '$js/Controller'

export default class Model {
  ... Model code
  static fxn(){
    controller.controllerFunction()
  }
}
```

**Utils File**(import doesn't work in this file, [Actual File](https://github.com/iiison/Flash/blob/master/js/utils.js)):

```
import controller from '$js/Controller'
export function someFunction(args) {
  const value = controller.get() // Throws an error saying `controller` is not defined
}
```

---

Here is the [Github Repo link](https://github.com/iiison/flash). Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: The utils file in your Github repository doesn't contain the code you are showing here.

Comment: Not sure what the `$` is in your `import`, some kind of alias? Anyway, trying to rule out the obvious: Did you try to use relative paths instead, just to see if it works?

Comment: @FelixKling ah, my bad, just push the code

Comment: @Potorr `$js` is webpack alias. and Yes, I tried the relative path too, but it didn't work :(

Comment: You have a circular dependency in your code. `utils` imports `Controller` and `Controller` imports `utils`. At the moment `Controller` calls `getTemplate`, it hasn't exported any value yet, hence `controller` is `undefined`.

Comment: Don't use classes if you only create a single instance. Export the class itself, or use an object literal and export that.

Comment: @FelixKling How to resolve the issue, I mean is there any good practice? As get templates has to be there in the `utils` file and it has to be called from this file.

One more thing, isn't the same thing happening in `Model` and `Controller`? `Model` imports `Controller` and opposite. How it is working in that case?